# Accessing dictionary from function in Python

Tags: python, function, dictionary, return

So I'm trying to take variables from one function, and continue to use them in another. I'm getting a KeyError when I try to run this. Any ideas? Cheers!

```
def find_pos():
    x = 1
    y = 12
    z = 3
    return { 'x':x, 'y':y, 'z':z }

def create(x, y, z):
    blah = x + y + z
    print 'blah'

testReturn = find_pos()
create(testReturn[x], testReturn[y], testReturn[z])
```

Comment: You're missing some quotes... `testReturn['x']`, etc.

Comment: You have to quote the keys.  Otherwise they're just undefined variables, right?  So use `testReturn['x']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access your dictionary by referring to your keys by a variable name that you have not defined. This is incorrect. Your dictionary keys were created using strings 'x', 'y' and 'z'. Therefore, you must access your data in your dictionary as such.

You want to do this:

```
create(testReturn['x'], testReturn['y'], testReturn['z'])
```

Better yet, since you seem to be doing some math operations on it, you can even use `get` instead, which will return `None` by default if it can't find the key. So, in your case, you can change this default, and set it to `0` instead:

```
create(testReturn.get('x', 0), testReturn.get('y', 0), testReturn.get('z', 0))
```